# How to do uniform crossover in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript,I am pretty confused with this uniform crossover stuff

What is uniform crossover ?[image]

I have two array Like this

```
var ParentOne = ["j1","j2","j3","j4","j5"];
var ParentTwo = ["j3","j4","j2","j1","j4"];
```

How to do it

I've just wrote just rand Selection array

```
function uniqueRandomInts(upperLimit, amount) {
    var possibleNumbers = _.range(upperLimit + 1);
    var shuffled = _.shuffle(possibleNumbers);
    return shuffled.slice(0, amount);
}
```

Comment: Is this about genetic algorithms?

Comment: Yes of course.....

Comment: Yes of course.....

Comment: You should get used to adding more detail to your Stack Overflow questions. Makes it easier for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Do you want to see my Whole GA Code ? if you need any info I'll be happy provide @Geuis

Comment: So as I'm reading about this on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm) it looks like there are different approaches going on. Even in the graphic you included, it doesn't look like the child is composed of 50/50 of each parent. Can you specify what your function inputs should be and what the expect outcome is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to create an output array with each element selected randomly from one of two input arrays. This is simple to do with a loop and basic random and rounding functions.

```
var ParentOne = ["j1","j2","j3","j4","j5"],
    ParentTwo = ["j3","j4","j2","j1","j4"],
    parents = [ParentOne, ParentTwo],
    output = []; output.length = ParentOne.length;

for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    output[i] = parents[Math.round(Math.random())][i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpBOoB

Since you're pretty new to js, the linked codepen is written in ES6 syntax. In particular, it makes use of destructuring to help with array length reordering and array concatenation and uses of `const` versus `var`.

In particular, there is a use case not covered by the currently accepted answer. What happens if the parents are not of equal size?

By just iterating over one parent or another, if that parent is shorter than the other then data from the second parent is lost. If the parent is longer than the other one, then both extra cycles are wasted because there is no matching data on the short parent *and* errors are introduced into the child array with `undefined` for each missing array index.

In the code below, we first sort the parent arrays so the shortest is first. After creating the child, we then concatenate any remaining data from the longest parent to the end of the child array.

```
const parentOne = ['j1','j2','j3','j4','j5'];
const parentTwo = ['j3','j4','j2','j1','j4'];

const parentThree = ['j1','j2','j3','j4','j5', '#', '##', '###'];
const parentFour = ['j3','j4','j2','j1','j4'];

const parentFive = ['j1','j2','j3','j4','j5', '#', '##', '###'];
const parentSix = ['j3','j4','j2','j1','j4'];

// ensure parentOne is the shortest
const fn = (...parents) => {
  // ensure shortest parent is first
  [parents] = parents[1].length < parents[0].length ? [[parents[1], parents[0]]] : [[parents[0], parents[1]]];

  // iterate over shortest parent
  let child = parents[0].map((item, i) => parents[Math.round(Math.random())][i]);

  // add the remaining elements from the longest array to the child
  if (parents[1].length > parents[0].length) {
    child = [...child, ...parents[1].slice(parents[0].length)];
  }

  return child;
}

console.log(fn(parentOne, parentTwo));
console.log(fn(parentThree, parentFour));
console.log(fn(parentFive, parentSix));
console.log('---');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on the fact, that both parents arrays have the same length and then just map the random items to a new array.

```js
var p1 = ["j1", "j2", "j3", "j4", "j5"],
    p2 = ["j3", "j4", "j2", "j1", "j4"],
    output = p1.map(function(_, i) {
        return [p1, p2][Math.round(Math.random())][i];
    });

console.log(output);
```

ES6

```js
var parent1 = ["j1", "j2", "j3", "j4", "j5"],
    parent2 = ["j3", "j4", "j2", "j1", "j4"],
    crossover = (p1, p2) => p1.map((_, i) => [p1, p2][Math.round(Math.random())][i]),
    output = crossover(parent1, parent2);

console.log(output);
```